# Automate user quotas for edquota to bypass vim

Tags: linux, vim, disk-space-utilization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Setting up disk quota on ubuntu for multiple users](https://serverfault.com/questions/226917/setting-up-disk-quota-on-ubuntu-for-multiple-users)

When assigning user quotas, one has to use `edquota`. However, this brings up the vim editor. Is there any way to bypass this. Observe this pseudocode

```
for username in usernames
 adduser username
 #########Filesystem######blocks######soft######hard######inodes######soft######hard
 edquota  /dev/hda2        596          0         0         1          0         0
```

I want to create 100 users (with 1/100th of the hard disk space), and I don't want to edit 100 files in vi/vim. Can I pass the values as arguments like above, or at least use a template file as  alluded to [here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.os.openbsd.misc/84666)

Comment: Yes sorry, I realize that now

Comment: No need to be sorry, duplicates are normal and expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all of the quotas are the same for all users you can set quota to one (prototypical) user and then use `edquota -p <proto_user> <user>` in for loop to duplicate the quotas of the prototypical user specified for each user specified.